# Facebook Registration Plugin and Name Field

Tags: facebook, facebook-application

I am trying to use FaceBook Registration Plugin (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/). It already has name field which I dont want to use instead i want to use my own First Name and Last Name fields Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

In the iframe url of the registration plugin, you pass in a json object listing the fields you would like on the form.

You can specify named fields (ie ones that exist within Facebook and so can be pre-populated) and also custom fields (anything that facebook doesn't know, but you might want). For example:

```
[
 {'name':'name'},
 {'name':'email'},
 {'name':'location'},
 {'name':'gender'},
 {'name':'birthday'},
 {'name':'password'},
 {'name':'like', 'description':'Do you like this plugin?', 'type':'checkbox',  'default':'checked'},
 {'name':'phone', 'description':'Phone Number', 'type':'text'},
 {'name':'anniversary','description':'Anniversary', 'type':'date'},
 {'name':'captain', 'description':'Best Captain', 'type':'select',    'options':{'P':'Jean-Luc Picard','K':'James T. Kirk'}},
 {'name':'force', 'description':'Which side?', 'type':'select',    'options':{'jedi':'Jedi','sith':'Sith'}, 'default':'sith'},
 {'name':'live', 'description':'Best Place to Live', 'type':'typeahead', 'categories':['city','country','state_province']},
 {'name':'captcha'}
]
```

It's worth noting that facebook already has [named fields for firstname and lastname](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/#named_fields) - you can ask for these and facebook will pre-populate the fields, but allow the user to change them.

All this is documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Answer (score 0):

If a user is registering to your site using the plugin, they are trying to connect via Facebook and therefore would like to have their information auto-filled. If they do not, then that Name field can work for a First Name and Last Name by allowing them to enter their full name.

The problem is, that plugin is optimized for use by Facebook users AND non-facebook users, shown here:

> The plugin also allows users who do
>   not have a Facebook account, or do not
>   wish to sign up for your site using
>   Facebook to use the same form as those
>   who are connecting with Facebook. This
>   eliminates the need to provide two
>   separate login experiences

With that said, they intend for this form to work for non-Facebook signups as well. I don't believe you can edit the forms since it uses an iframe and calls those fields through it with no user-allowed editing of the plugin. However, this doesn't mean that you could use the Facebook API to create your own plugin, or maybe a CMS you would use would have its own as well...

Another option is to have your own form, but have a "Sign In with Facebook!" link.

To answer your question directly: No, it does not look like it is editable in any way, but there are alternatives if you do not appreciate the way that the form already works.